# How to insert elements into a multiple nested XML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I have an XML in the following form:

```xml
<PROJECT>
    <UPDATE_TYPE>FULL</UPDATE_TYPE>
    <PROJECT_NAME>GEN20x_BALBOA</PROJECT_NAME>
    <BLOCK>
        <BLOCK1>
            <TYPE>BOOT</TYPE>
            <TASK>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="aaa" />
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="qqq" />
            </TASK>
            <TASK>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="mno" />
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="xzy" />
            </TASK>
            <TASK>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="rrr" />
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="uuu" />
            </TASK>
        </BLOCK1>
    </BLOCK>
</PROJECT>
```

I need to insert another `<INSTALL_OPTIONS>` inside *all* the `TASK` tags, the result thus should look like this:

```xml
        <BLOCK1>
            <TYPE>BOOT</TYPE>
            <TYPE>BOOT</TYPE>
            <TASK>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="aaa" />
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="qqq" />
        
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="new"/>
            </TASK>
            <TASK>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="mno" />
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="xzy" />
        
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="new"/>
            </TASK>
            <TASK>
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="rrr" />
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="uuu" />
        
                <INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="new"/>
            </TASK>
        </BLOCK1>
```

I tried the below approach but was able to insert only to the first tag:

```
task = root.find('.//TASK')
io = ET.SubElement(task, 'INSTALL_OPTIONS')
io.attrib['softwareType'] = 'new'
```

How to get it inserted at all the 3 places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `insert()` method. Assuming each `Task` has exactly two `INSTALL_OPTIONS`, Try something like this:

```
tasks = root.findall('.//TASK')
new_io= ET.fromstring('<INSTALL_OPTIONS softwareType="new"/>')
for task in tasks:
    task.insert(2,new_io)
print(ET.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output should be your expected output.